# my regex code not working perfectly need assistance

Tags: regex, notepad++

i am trying to remove all lines that its password doesnt follow my standard policy
username:password
the policy are

```
Passwords are after ":" And password policy is that the password must be 7 to 32 characters long and The password must contain a mix of letters, numbers, and/or special characters also passwords containing only letters or only numbers are not accepted
```

```
username:Password42
Username52@:sssdt3
user:Pass!626795
use:uss
```

removing all lines only leaving

```
username:Password42
user:Pass!626795
```

i tried using regex, Made this one but it doesnt work perfectly, Why so? Anyone can fix it?

```
^:*(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])|(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+])).*$\R*
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you can consider using is

```
^[^:\r\n]+:(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,32}$).*\R?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zsuj6v/2)

Details:

- `^` - start of a line
- `[^:\r\n]+` - 1 or more chars other than a colon, CR and LF
- `:` -  a colon
- `(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,32}$)` - negative lookahead that fails the match if there are seven to thirty-two chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location, that contain both a digit, lower- or uppercase letter
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars (the rest of the line)
- `\R?` - an optional line break sequence

NOTE you may add more alternatives to the negative lookahead. E.g. replace `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` with `(?:(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()_+]))` to also require digits and special chars of your choice in the pattern to negate.

Comment: Thanks but i want it that it have at least 1 capital letter please

Comment: @glalali See the bottom of the answer: add the alternatives as you need, in case you must have a capital letter, split `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` into  `(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])`. See `^[^:\r\n]+:(?!(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{7,32}$).*\R?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zsuj6v/2).